# How to pass $http response value to another function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have these two functions. I need to pass the response value of $scope.submit to $scope.addTeams. This is working but I know this is a really stupid approach. What is the best approach?

```js
 $scope.submit = function() {
   $http.post('/api/createclub/', {
     club: $scope.club
   }).success(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
     $rootScope.clubId = response._id;
   });
 };

 $scope.addTeams = function() {

   console.log($rootScope.clubId);

   $state.go('createTeam', {
     clubId: $rootScope.clubId
   });
   $scope.cancel();
 };
```

Comment: What you are doing will work, however, addTeams won't have a clubId unless it isn't called until after the post is complete. It's a race condition, that i don't see an easy way out of given the small bit of code provided.

Comment: Yes that I understand. To provide you with more insight on what I am trying to achieve, I have two different buttons that trigger these functions.

Comment: Disable one until the other is complete, or turn them into one button.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with

```
$scope.submit = function() {
      $http.post('/api/createclub/', {
        club: $scope.club
      }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.addTeams(response._id);
      });
    };

    $scope.addTeams = function(id) {

      $state.go('createTeam', {
        clubId: id
      });
      $scope.cancel();
    };
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this. I had tried this as well but $scope.addTeams() is triggered by ng-click. By following this approach however the $scope.addTeams() function gets called and the state changes, which shouldn't

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're using submit AND addTeams on a button click?

Comment: Sounds like they are on two different buttons?!

Comment: What's triggering the `submit`?

Comment: Yes. Basically this function i.e. Addteams should trigger only when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have another button that triggers the submit function

Comment: Um, the logic seems odd but `@scope.clubId = response._id` in `submit` and then check the `$scope.clubId` in `addTeams` before changing state?

Comment: @Wainage Tried that as well. Gives me undefined. Basically, what I have done is that I have called two functions open(), submit() on a button. open() is for a modal which would take image as an upload and on successful upload would show the button for addTeams(). So when that button is clicked, it should take me to the state for adding teams with the $stateParams clubId. I hope that made sense

Comment: Why don't you show the `addTeams` button if `$scope.cludId != null`? Then it MUST be there.

Comment: Well let's see. I am thinking of something. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your addTeams function in your $http post response handler, passing in the id value you are currently setting on rootScope

What you shouldn't really do is set properties like this on the rootScope

Comment: I had tried this approach but $scope.addTeams() is triggered by ng-click. By following this approach however the $scope.addTeams() function gets called and the state changes, which basically shouldn't.